# How do I remove unwanted characters from a list created through python from yfinance?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am pulling tickers from yfinance into a list and attempting to print the list. When printing, the list prints with characters added to each stock ticker. I would like to remove these characters and have tried using the `lstrip` and `rstrip` functions but I continue to get the added characters. Below is the input code:

```
for i in edited_buylist:
    i = str(i)
    i = i.lstrip('yfinance.Ticker object <')
for i in edited_buylist:
    i = str(i)
    i = i.rstrip('>')
print("The list of securities that are at or near support points are: ", str(edited_buylist))
```

Below is the output of that code:

```
The list of securities that are at or near support points are:  [yfinance.Ticker object <VVV>]
```

'''

I would like to remove the "yfinance.Ticker object<" and ">".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ticker` attribute:

```
edited_buylist = [i.ticker for i in edited_buylist]
print("The list of securities that are at or near support points are: ", str(edited_buylist))
```